# android with github actions

Tags: android, github, github-actions

I'm trying to automate my versioning in android using actions, its my first time using this technology
so I have 3 commands:
./gradlew bumpPatch
./gradlew bumpMinor
./gradlew bumpMajor
How can I determinate which one execute from a PR to master for example :

branch fix/foo --> execute ./gradlew bumpPatch

branch feat/foo --> execute ./gradlew bumpMinor

branch perf/foo --> execute ./gradlew bumpMajor

and how I can do it.

I'm following semantic release so maybe it's better execute the command from the commit message but still don't know how to do both so help it's appreciated.

```
name: Android CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following workflow. It only triggers on pull requests against main. It uses conditional steps (`if`) with an expression that uses the function [`startsWith`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#startswith).

```
name: Android CI

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew
    - run: ./gradlew bumpPatch
      if: startsWith(github.head_ref, 'fix/')
    - run: ./gradlew bumpMinor
      if: startsWith(github.head_ref, 'feat/')
    - run: ./gradlew bumpMajor
      if: startsWith(github.head_ref, 'perf/')
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build
```